# TYPO3 Routing: Multiple Path Segments

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am trying to generate tree URLs for some categories.
The URLs should look like this: `/category1/subcategory1/subcategory2`.
The amount of path segments should be flexible since I don't know how deep the categories will be.

I got the first path segment working with the following config and a **custom Mapper:**

```
ProductsPlugin:
  type:              Extbase
  limitToPages:
    - 5
  extension:         MyExt
  plugin:            Products
  routes:
    -
      routePath:   '/{category_title}'
      _controller: 'Products::list'
      _arguments:
        category_title: id
  defaultController: 'Products::list'
  requirements:
    category_title: '[0-9]{1..6}'
  aspects:
    category_title:
      type: ProductsValueMapper
```

**The Mapper looks like this:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyExt\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedMappableAspectInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

class ProductsValueMapper implements PersistedMappableAspectInterface
{
    use SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        /**
         * returns one or more path segments
         * e.g. category1 or category1/subcategory1
         */
        return $slug; 
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        /**
         * returns the id of the category from the last path segment
         */
        return $id;
    }
}
```

For just a single category it works fine. But as soon as a subcategory is requested the code breaks. The link to the subcategory only contains the path segment of the subcategory, e.g. `/subcategory1`, but not the one of the category.

It's clear to me why that is, since I only add the id of the subcategory to LinkViewHelper: `<f:link.action controller="Products" action="list" arguments="{id: 5}">Test Link</f:link.action>`. But I can

Which screws do I need to adjust to make the URLs work also for any depth of subcategories?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow `/` as requirements. The default requirement is `[^/]+` and you specified only a number.

This should work:

```
ProductsPlugin:
  requirements:
    category_title: .+
```

See also Symfony-Docs: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing/slash_in_parameter.html